# Differentiability and basic definitions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

If $f+g$ is differentiable at $a$, must $f$ and $g$ be differentiable at $a$?

If " and $f$ is differentiable at $a$, must $g$ be differentiable at $a$?

If $f*g$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f$ is differentiable at $a$, must $g$ be differentiable at $a$? Do you need any conditions on $f$?

Comment: There's a typo in the second question.

Comment: In the first one, have you tried proving it by first principles?

Comment: I mean for the first one, I know thats true.  It was a group of questions, so I figured I would check all of them

Comment: @GitGud, there is no typo, " means the same thing as above.

Comment: Are you just wanting to know if you got the right answers, is that it?

Comment: yea. I think 1 is true, 2 might be true and 3 is false

Comment: You're right. The first and second are true and the third only holds if $f(a)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

1) In general, it doesn't even guarantee that $f$ or $g$ are continuous at $a$.  The strategy here should be to think of two functions which sum to a relatively simple function but are not themselves simple.  So the simplest function I can think of is a constant function.  Thus we'll let $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$ in some set $E$ and $0$ else, and let $g(x) = 1$ for all $x$ not in $E$ and $0$ else.  Then we're guaranteed that $f(x) = g(x) = 1$, for all $x$.  Now the trick is to cleverly choose $E$ so that there's no possibility of $f$ or $g$ being nice near $a$.  You're more than welcome to come up with such an $E$.

2) On the other hand, yes.  We know that the sum and difference of differentiable functions is differentiable (the class of differentiable functions forms a "vector space" under pointwise addition and scala multiplication).  So we'd like to have two functions $u$ and $v$ which are both differentiable at $a$ so that $u + v = g$.  Can you think of two such functions?

1) and 2) should help you figure out 3) and what can go wrong in 3).